# Выполнение sql-запроса в bash-скрипте

Tags: shell, bash, sql

Каков синтаксис sql-запроса (обычного select-а) в bash-скрипте?

Comment: bash и sql? Это откуда? Если речь идёт о вызове из bash'а программы-клиента для sql-сервера, то ответ зависит от клиента и, соответственно, сервера.

Answer (score 4):

Для большинства СУБД можно просто передать запрос в stdin через конвейер:

```
# postgres
echo "SELECT * FROM tbl" | psql -Uuser -Wpassword dbname

# mysql
echo "SELECT * FROM tbl" | mysql -uuser -ppassword dbname
```

Если ответ нужно обработать, то:

```
RESULT=$(echo "SELECT * FROM tbl" | psql -Uuser -Wpassword dbname)
```

Или:

```
IFS=$'\n';
for row in $(echo "SELECT * FROM tbl" | psql -At -Uuser -Wpassword dbname); do 
    # ...
    echo $row
done
```

Comment: это нужно писать в файле с расширением sh? (вопрос к Ilya Pirogov) и что такое IFS и после for row in $(echo "SELECT * FROM tbl" | psql -At -Uuser -Wpassword dbnamе) точно нужна ; (просто вспоминается аналогия с обыкновенными языками)

Comment: > и что такое IFS

[internal field separator](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#IFSREF)

> и после for row in $(echo "SELECT * FROM tbl" | psql -At -Uuser -Wpassword dbnamе) точно нужна ;

Без `;` будет так:

    for row in $(...)
    do
        ...
    done

PS Если вы не знаете bash, к чему тогда такие вопросы?

Comment: а как записать результаты sql-запроса в файл через пробел каждую запись? Как записать каждую запись sql-запроса в файл на отдельной строке?

Answer (score 1):

Можно ещё так

```
myvariable=$(mysql database -s -u$user -p$password<<<"SELECT A, B, C FROM table_a")
```